# Trouble selecting particular entry in list

Tags: ansible

I am having a devil of a time sorting this out so any help is appreciated. I know I need to use *selectattr* but cannot figure out how exactly.

Using ansible  I need to find the address associated with the neighbor that has a route map named BGP_TO_EC applied. I know  *selectattr* will be involved but cannot figure out how exactly.

TIA

Parsed config:

```yaml
address_family:
  - afi: ipv4
    neighbor:
      - activate: true
        address: 10.1.1.1
        nexthop_self:
          set: true
        route_maps:
          - name: BGP_TO_EC
            out: true
  - afi: ipv4
    neighbor:
      - activate: true
        address: 10.2.2.2
        remote_as: 3549
        version: 4
    network:
      - address: 10.3.3.3
        mask: 255.255.255.252
    vrf: somevrf
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the data

```yaml
address_family:
  - afi: ipv4
    neighbor:
    - activate: true
      address: 10.1.1.1
      nexthop_self:
        set: true
      route_maps:
      - name: BGP_TO_EC
        out: true
  - afi: ipv4
    neighbor:
    - activate: true
      address: 10.2.2.2
      remote_as: 3549
      version: 4
    network:
    - address: 10.3.3.3
      mask: 255.255.255.252
    vrf: somevrf
```

---

Simplify the data a bit. Put the below declarations into the [*vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) as appropriate

```yaml
neighbors_raw: "{{ address_family|json_query(nr_query) }}"
nr_query: "[].neighbor[].{address: address, names: route_maps[].name}"
```

gives

```yaml
neighbors_raw:
  - address: 10.1.1.1
    names:
    - BGP_TO_EC
  - address: 10.2.2.2
    names: null
```

Replace the *null* with an empty list

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        neighbors_list: "{{ neighbors_list|d([]) +
                            [item|combine({'names': item.names|
                                                    ternary(item.names, [])})] }}"
      loop: "{{ neighbors_raw }}"
```

gives

```yaml
neighbors_list:
  - address: 10.1.1.1
    names:
    - BGP_TO_EC
  - address: 10.2.2.2
    names: []
```

Now, you can select the address

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ neighbors_list|selectattr('names', 'contains', 'BGP_TO_EC')|
                                map(attribute='address')|list }}"
```

gives a list because, generally, there might be more selected items

```yaml
  msg:
  - 10.1.1.1
```

You might want to select the first one

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ neighbors_list|selectattr('names', 'contains', 'BGP_TO_EC')|
                                map(attribute='address')|first }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: 10.1.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed. I am new to Ansible so it took me a bit to read and digest the documentation of JSONQuery and understand what exactly this did but once I understood it I was good to go and learned a few things.